# Missing Date/time picker in Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-10, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a new Windows 10 laptop with Excel 2016.  I need to support a spreadsheet that has a datetime picker.

When I start the spreadsheet, I get an error "Could not load an object because it is not available on this machine."  I go to the VBA code, and get the error "Compile error: Method or data member not found" on the line

```
UserForm1.DTPicker1 = Now()
```

Where and how do I get or enable the date time picker?

This might be related: [Cannot use Date and Time Picker in Office 2013](https://superuser.com/questions/762967/cannot-use-date-and-time-picker-in-office-2013), but I don't even see the file mscomct2.ocx

Comment: Did you try what was suggested in that question you linked, and make the location of the file a Trusted Location in Excel?  Are you using a 32 or 64-bit version of Excel?

Comment: I don't have the file, so I'm not sure how making that part of the OS trusted would help.  I'm assuming 64 bit, but I'm not sure how to tell.

Comment: "I'm not sure how making that part of the OS trusted would help" Me neither, but the single answer on the question you linked suggests that fixed it for them, so I'm clarifying if you attempted it already or not.  "I'm assuming 64 bit" If it's 64-bit, that's probably your problem, as the DTPicker you're using is a 32-bit ActiveX control that doesn't exist/work in 64-bit Office. "but I'm not sure how to tell": [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203980/detect-whether-office-is-32bit-or-64bit-via-the-registry).

Comment: My version of Excel 2016 is 32 bit.